# What is the proper URL to use when loading a gif from Imgur to use in Glide?

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I'm looking into using Glide to access gifs off an image hosting website instead of having them all stored in the app within the assets folder. I have Glide working in the sense that it will load the image I specify when the original URL fails.

```
ImageView imageViewGif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);

    String gifUrl = "http://imgur.com/gallery/XgbZdeA";

    Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(gifUrl)
            .asGif()
            .error(R.drawable.alternator_pic)
            .into(imageViewGif);
```

So it loads up alternator pic just fine but I am unable to get it to load an image or gif from the specified URL. What am I missing?

Comment: You mean this link (---> http://imgur.com/gallery/XgbZdeA) doesn't work? Seems the dog image in it is not a gif tho...

Comment: I'll have to check the link again. There were two seperate links for some reason(one in the top URL bar and one on the side by a button that said copy. Either way no image comes up so it seems it isn't loading the image from online for some reason.

Comment: Can you please give the exact link you are trying to load the image from?

Comment: @user3793589 sorry for the late response http://imgur.com/a/tbGrk